# How to use phpcs with url?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I want to report PHP 5.4 incompatibility issues and for that I am suggested phpCodeSniffer for Ubuntu Server 14.04, I am able to run the command to generate reports for local/path like:

```
$ phpcs codesniffer/Sniffs/PHP/*.php
```

but want to generate reports using url instead of the local path (like `$ phpcs http://path.to/folder`. Google does not do much :( Please help!

Comment: Unless your server is misconfigured, you can't see the PHP source code through a URL, only the rendered markup; so what exactly do you expect phpcs to report on with a URL?

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker for clearing that phpcs cannot sniff using url. I was expecting too much out of phpcs I think.